# Entity Framework not creating table correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-applications, entity-framework-migrations

I am working on creating a .NET Web Application and have just discovered Entity Framework.  I am very new to this and have been going through a tutorial using Code First Migration.  I am trying to seed data into a few tables and one of them is not getting any data added to it.

Part of my initialization file is shown below.

```
 var schedules = new List<Schedule>
        {
        new Schedule{ScheduleID = 20, EmployeeID = 1, JobID = 10},
        new Schedule{ScheduleID = 21, EmployeeID = 2, JobID = 11}
        };
```

The table gets created with the correct fields, but the data is not entered into it.  I am very confused why the other two tables worked but not this one.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Context file

```
public class Context : DbContext
{

    public Context() : base("Context")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Schedule Model:

```
 public class Schedule
{
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int JobID { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the whole implementation of youir initiaitlization. At least the method implementation.

Comment: Not enough info. How are you seeding? (migration or database initializer). You made a schedule list in memory, but where are you saving it in EF? i.e. `SaveChanges()` needs to be called.